# how to position image a little outside a slanted div - used clip path for slanting

Tags: html, css

I have used clip path property to create a slanted bottom div.

Now, the next part is to position the image in such a way so it shows a little bit outside this div.

the problem is that this image is not showing outside the div at all.
it just shows up in the slanted div in the same shape but doesnt show up outside it.

here's a link to my codepen - https://codepen.io/silentarrowz/pen/wYdEOM

how do I make that image go outside the div too.

I have tried doing this with skew property too but that has the same problem too.

here's the code too

```
.slanted {
    background-color:red;
    height:200px;
/*     -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 56%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 96%, 0 100%); */
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 50%);
     clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

.baboon{
  width:40%;
  position:relative;
  top:10px;
}
```

Desired output could be something like in this codepen

Ah,yes. if the same effect of slant and image positioning can be achieved with something other than clip-path , then I am quite willing to use that.

https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/rObREE

Comment: What's the desired output, and do you have to use clip?

Comment: updated original post with link to desired output. 
you see how the image is going outside the slanted div??

Mine is not doing so at the moment.
how do I make that happen?

Comment: So I'm not sure I understand, the 2nd example you give literally shows you one of several examples of how to accomplish exactly what you're asking if you see the `linear-gradient` added to the `background-image` attribute. Or are you wanting to know specifically how to do it with `clip`?

Comment: no, it uses an image instead of div.
but yeah. if you could tell me how to do it with clip that would be great

Comment: [like this](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/EdXbEj) would be one way, personally though I'd do it differently than clip.

Comment: could you share that different method too, if it's not too much too ask?
and why not clip. does it not work on all browsers?? any disadvantages that's stopping you from using it??

Comment: and thanks for such a quick demo with the solution. so, it was basically the translate property you used there that fixed it??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181694/discussion-between-faraz-and-chris-w).